# Whats the best practice to use UpdatePanel with asp.net repeater?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, repeater

What is the best practice to use `UpdatePanel` or `Radajaxpanel` with asp.net repeater, the pagination sometimes is not working properly. When I remove the `UpdatePanel` control, the pagination works perfectly, but the pages have to reload.

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 10px;">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2 align="left" class="page-header">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-width"></span>Latest Stories (324 stories)
                <div class="pagination">
                    <div class="pages">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text=" < " OnClick="lnkPrev_Click" />
                        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text=" > " OnClick="lnkNext_Click" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2>
                </h2>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpttext" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                    <div class="thumbnail" style="min-height: 280px">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>
                                <a style="color: black;" href='<%# "item.aspx?id=" & Eval("Id")%>'>
                                    <%# Eval("PeopleNamesByAppearanceOrder")%></a>
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                <%# Eval("PeopleNamesByAppearanceOrder")%></p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" class="label label-danger">22.30$</a> <a href="#" class="label label-default">
                                    Download</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <img width="350px" height="300px" class="img-responsive" src='<%# "../" & Eval("thumimage") %>'
                            alt='<%#Eval("PeopleNamesByAppearanceOrder") %>'>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbfooter" style="min-height: 35px; background-color: #dddddd;">
                        <div style="float: left;">
                            <i class="fa fa-download" style="padding-left: 20px; color: #154979;" aria-hidden="true">
                            </i>| <i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i>22.34
                        </div>
                        <div style="float: right;">
                            <img src="../img/small_logo_item.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: There is no best practice. There are just issues that you fix. You haven't described your issue sufficiently, just said it's "not working" which could mean anything.

Comment: I mean when I click on Next page ">"  it works but when I click on previous page "<" its not working.

Comment: Again, you need to describe "not working". I don't know what that phrase means in this context. What specifically happens? Does the page stay the same? Does the page refresh and come back on the first page? Do you get a JavaScript error? Do you get a YSOD? You need to specifically describe the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: The page stay the same when I click previous , but it works to move to next page when I click forward link ">"

Comment: Could it be that the problem is not in the `UpdatePanel` or the `Repeater`, but rather your custom pagination?